# RubyMotion Day Number of year for today

Tags: rubymotion

I want to generate the current day number using RubyMotion code. I have looked at several IOS solutions but I'm not experienced enough to translate the code successfully to RubyMotion.

I am currently at the following point:

```ruby
def today
  NSDate.today
end

def day_number
  NSDate.from_components (day: today)
end
```

When I run the above it gives me an return of 3852055-06-16 00:00:00 +0100. I thought that the 3852055 part was seconds but it doesn't seem to equate to either todays date or to 16th of June - and in any case why should it be returning 06-16 instead of 02-08?? Totally confused here.

I just want to get todays day number. As I write the date is 2nd August 2014 and the day number should be 214 so I'm obviously way out somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
daynum = NSCalendar.currentCalendar.ordinalityOfUnit(NSDayCalendarUnit, inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit, forDate:NSDate.date)
```

Now suppose you have the date in the form of a string, and you want to get the day number for it:

```
datestr = "2014-01-01 11:08:56 +0000"
```

First create an `NSDateFormatter` to convert the `String` into an `NSDate`

```
df = NSDateFormatter.new
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
mydate = df.dateFromString(datestr)
daynum = NSCalendar.currentCalendar.ordinalityOfUnit(NSDayCalendarUnit, inUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit, forDate:mydate)
```

If your date string is simpler:

```
datestr = "2014-01-01"
```

just use a simpler `dateFormat` string:

```
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanks a million it works perfectly. I spent around 3 hours yesterday trying to puzzle that out and couldn't. One more question if I may - I'm also using Turnkey to archive a user set date but as far as I can tell, it will only archive a string ie:Turnkey.archive(@date, "userDate") Consequently, when it is unarchived it is still a string and I want to use the unarchived data in relation to the current day number (as in your provided solution) Obviously, as it's a string this doesn't work. Is there a way around this or else if not, is there a better solution? Cheers

Comment: So you need to turn a date string into an `NSDate`? What does one of these date strings look like?

Comment: Actually, I have just inserted a puts user_date.class and it says the class is time and not a string as I thought. When I try to use it in a calculation with the code you provided I get the error Time can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError) Any idea how to correct that?

Comment: What do you get if you type `puts user_date.to_s`

Comment: 2014-01-01 11:08:56 +0000 which is what it is currently set to. So, it's giving the date and time but I have the date picker set like this: @myDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate. IE: with only the date and no time?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at `motion-support` gem and especially at [`core-exttime`](https://github.com/rubymotion/motion-support#core_exttime).

You can play with dates as you want:

```
=> Mon, 04 Aug 2014
(main)> Time
=> Time
(main)> Time.today
=> 2014-08-04 00:00:00 +0200
(main)> Date.today.day
=> 4
(main)> Time.today.day
=> 4
```

and a lot more.